# Redirect link with SameSite=Strict causing timeout

Tags: samesite

I have searched and while some may think the other answers should be enough I haven't really been able to comprehend why I need it set to lax to work, nor what implications that really means.

There are 2 applications (1. SaaS tool, 2. OnPrem Tool)
SaaS tool is Single Sign On.
OnPrem tool is NTLM Auth.

When in the SaaS tool it has a link to the OnPrem application url. 
The OnPrem web app has sameSite=strict OoB.

I don't understand, because the applications aren't linked to each other, why the cookies matter?:

OnPrem App SameSite=Strict - It's just a link to the OnPrem application website why would it be causing a timeout (I know there may be many underlying factors). When it times out, if I hit refresh it logs me into the OnPrem application. 
When the link is in an email, it logs people straight in to the OnPrem tool.

OnPrem App SameSite=Lax - Works just fine.

Is SameSite Lax something to worry if we use that setting? And why would it still not work if it's strict?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the cookie controlling the user's session is set to `SameSite=Strict` then it will never be sent on the initial navigation request to the page. So, it's probably more strict than you want. `SameSite=Lax` allows for the cookie to be sent on "safe" top-level navigations, like following a link from a bookmark or email.

https://twitter.com/rowan_m/status/1281638212822343682